# Classic Asp insert to DB with table that has schema

Tags: sql, asp-classic, schema

I'm the lucky winner of fixing a legacy code base for adding some stuff to a DB.

I have a tabel in a schema like this

```
CREATE TABLE [agreements].approved
(
    id int not null IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    DomainName varchar(50) not null,
    ApplicantFirstname varchar(50) not null,
    ApplicantLastname varchar(50) not null,
    OwnerFirstname varchar(50),
    OwnerLastname varchar(50),
    OwnerCompany varchar(50),
    ViewedAppendix3 bit not null,
    ApprovedDate datetime DEFAULT GETDATE(),
)
```

**Now to the question. How do I insert a new row to a tabell that has a schema using classic ASP? This is what im trying with:**

```
agreeSQL = "insert into [agreements].approved(DomainName, ApplicantFirstname, ApplicantLastname, OwnerFirstname, OwnerLastname, ViewedAppendix3) values('" & domain1 &"','" & owner & "','" & owner &"','" & owner & "','" & owner & "','" & owner &"','TRUE')"
conn.execute agreeSQL ' conn is a working connection to the DB.
```

This simply fails with a 500 internal exception. And here comes the kicker. I cant see any error messages and all the changes I do is on a live production server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with the schema. It was the SQL that was incorrect. It was a bit tircky to find since I couldnt print any test messages.

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable "Send error to Browser" in IIS to see ASP error messages in the browser. Sorry for the German screenshot :-)
[image]

Comment: +1 for good recommendation. Only problem for me is that this very bad legacy site sends me to a new page as soon as there comes a server error. So if I get a 500 internal server error then it will send me to a fake error page. I dont have the authorization to change this to so that I can do some debugging.

Comment: Another tip: Use Nlog as logging tool. It has an COM interface and can be used in ASP. http://nlog-project.org/wiki/COM_logging_API

Answer (score 1):

Try using `'TRUE'` instead of `'1'` to store the `BIT` value.

Comment: Tried with 'TRUE'. And thats the way to do it but it still didn't solve my problem I still belive it fails on the schema. Any idé about that?

Comment: I assume you have tried printing out `agreeSQL` and executing it directly to confirm that its not a data issue.

Comment: Yeah just did that and Found another problem with my SQL, had one to many values. And now it seems to work. So I guess I was correct with the schema from the beginning but not careful enough when writing the rest of the SQL. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You've got your last value, the bit field, wrapped in quotes and it should not be.

Comment: I changed it to 'TRUE' as suggested by @Aziz. But thanks for your input